# Edit metadata entered during beta testing for App store final release

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I need to distribute my iOS app to the external testers. I upload the binary for the app, and it is now shown on the pre release section in iTunes Connect.

But I did not receive all the needed information to fill in the app meta. Is it ok if I fill in some sample data for now, and towards the end, replace it with the original values.

This include the app name, bundle ID, Contact Information, email id etc.

Please comment on this.

Comment: Please note that I have submitted a version to the app store for beta testing app review. I am not sure I will be able to edit the bundle id now.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to change everything but the bundle id that you declared in the `Apple Developer Center` and then used to create the app on `iTunes Connect`

As it seems to be the first release of your app you could also completely trash I and restart from the ground, losing of course the fact that your app already has passed the External beta Review process.